# How to insert random values to a table field?

Tags: mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Populate table with random data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371503/sql-populate-table-with-random-data)

How to insert random values to table field? like if i want to enter 100 virtual phone numbers of 100 students, how can i do that? Thanks.
Ps: It should be a 9 digit random number?

Comment: You're wanting us to help you with your homework?

Comment: this is not my homework, its a very big project, this is just a small bit where I'm stuck and I have wasted lot of time on this. I have to create 1000's of random entries for many tables.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude. I just thought it was interesting that you tagged the question with the word "homework".

Comment: So any help with the solution?

Comment: Actually, if you googled "mysql random" you'd find your answer pretty quickly.  You're just wasting everybody's time if you don't do your research before posting.

Comment: google has more answers on "selecting random entries" and very few(which I'm not understanding) for "inserting random entries"

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following site to generate sample random data: http://www.generatedata.com

Go to the Generator tab, select ResultType as SQL, provide the field names and click the Generate button.

Comment: @user1291453 someone can help. yourself!