# How to create and insert n rows of test data of random strings into table in Postgres with SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

In SQL in Postgres, how do I create and insert `n` number of rows of test data with random strings length `x`?

e.g.,

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text_column TEXT);
-- now insert n rows of test data into my_table, with random
-- strings of length x for my_text_column
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is already available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371503/sql-populate-table-with-random-data)

```
create table yourtable as select descr from 
          (SELECT generate_series(1,10) AS id,md5(random()::text) AS descr)s;
```